# IP limited access and 404 shown if false

Tags: php, ip, http-status-code-404

I want to show a certain page only to users with a specific IP, and if the IP doesn't match, make the page look like it doesn't exist (show 404 error page without redirecting).

I have the part which checks the IP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'IP address' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1')
echo '<li><a href="page.php"><b>Page</b></a></li>';
```

However, I don't know how to show the 404 error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the 404 header and `echo` out the contents of your 404 page, if you have one; otherwise, make one like you would any other page, and echo it out.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo file_get_contents("404.html");
```